# Problem calling variable of data frame and printing results in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function that will return the largest number of digits before and after a decimal, i.e. c(45.677,3.4) would return "2 3", the largest values. I have the general idea of how I want to do this down using this code and test data

```
test <- data.frame(V1 = c(1:10), V2 = c(seq(from= 1.456643235, to = 10.456643235, by = 1 )),
                   V3 = c(rep(4.56000, times = 10)), v4 = c(21:30) )

TEST
       V1        V2   V3 v4
    1   1  1.456643 4.56 21
    2   2  2.456643 4.56 22
    3   3  3.456643 4.56 23
    4   4  4.456643 4.56 24
    5   5  5.456643 4.56 25
    6   6  6.456643 4.56 26
    7   7  7.456643 4.56 27
    8   8  8.456643 4.56 28
    9   9  9.456643 4.56 29
    10 10 10.456643 4.56 30
```

```
for (i in ncol(test2) {
  x.1 <- test2[2]
  if (is.numeric(x.1) == TRUE) {
    breakdown <- as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(test2[,2]), split = ".", fixed=T))
    firstDigit <- max(nchar(as.character(breakdown[1,])))
    secondDigit <- max(nchar(as.character(breakdown[2,])))
    print(firstDigit)
    print(secondDigit)
  }
}
```

This code should loop over the columns of my test data, if it's numerical data then it creates a dataframe from the values of the current column with a structure like this, where the first row is the number before the decimal and the second row is the number after my decimal, using V3 of my test data.
Essentially taking the variable on its side and splitting it by decimal. Creating a new temporary dataframe called "breakdown" that allows me to then pull the largest value from each row

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 56 | 56 | 56 | 56 | 56 |

and so on.

I am doing it in this manner because I want the largest value of each location in the number. So rather than just counting all of the digits in a column and just assuming the largest number in total would be with the most value places, I want to know if another number may have a larger number before the decimal than another number has after the decimal.

i.e., if given c(23.4, 4.678654) I would get 2 and 6 back. (also note that in the example I give a vector just for clarity, the function will assume the input of a column within a dataframe)

When writing this function I was testing it outside of the loop and did get the results I was looking for

```
y <- as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(test2$V2), split = ".", fixed=T))
max(nchar(as.character(y2[1,])))
max(nchar(as.character(y2[2,])))
```

This creates a dataframe with the correct values and then returns the largest number of digits within each row like I want it to right now. However when I run it as

```
as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(test2[,2]), split = ".", fixed=T))
or 
as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(test2[2]), split = ".", fixed=T))
```

I get an incorrect result, I believe as a result of calling the variable through brackets instead of the $ notation.

Since calling

```
as.character(test2$V2)
```

gives me
[1] "1.456643235"  "2.456643235"  "3.456643235"  "4.456643235"  "5.456643235"  "6.456643235"  "7.456643235"  "8.456643235"  "9.456643235"  "10.456643235"

which is correct and useable for my function

but calling

```
as.character(test2[,2])
```

Gives me
"c(1.456643235, 2.456643235, 3.456643235, 4.456643235, 5.456643235, 6.456643235, 7.456643235, 8.456643235, 9.456643235, 10.456643235)" - which messes up the strsplit function.

To my understanding you can't really call a variable by the $ notation in a for loop since you're looping through ncol as a numeric value and not the actual name of the variable, but that seems to be what causes the issue - is there a better way to call my data so that it remains usable in my function? Additionally, the print function doesn't do anything when included in the for loop as is, is this a related problem to the way the variable is called?

EDIT: The initial problem was caused by haven importing SPSS data as a tibble whereas I was interacting with it as a dataframe. Test is the original data I created with dput

```
structure(list(V1 = 1:10, V2 = c(1.456643235, 2.456643235, 3.456643235, 
4.456643235, 5.456643235, 6.456643235, 7.456643235, 8.456643235, 
9.456643235, 10.456643235), V3 = c(4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 
4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56), v4 = 21:30), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

But since I want the function to be able to interact with Haven attributes eventually, namely the width of a variable, I had saved test with write_sav and then opened that in SPSS to give it all the attributes and then reimported the dataset as test2 with read_spss. Giving

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
), format.spss = "F2.0"), V2 = structure(c(1.456643235, 2.456643235, 
3.456643235, 4.456643235, 5.456643235, 6.456643235, 7.456643235, 
8.456643235, 9.456643235, 10.456643235), format.spss = "F2.0"), 
    V3 = structure(c(4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 
    4.56, 4.56, 4.56), format.spss = "F2.0"), v4 = structure(c(21, 
    22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), format.spss = "F2.0")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

The result was the same dataset but as a different structure, causing the syntax error.

Now knowing this, the updated loop

```
 for (i in ncol(test2)) {
    x.1 <- test2[[i]]
    if (is.numeric(x.1) == TRUE) {
    breakdown <- as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(test2[[i]]), split = ".", fixed=T))
    leftHand <- max(nchar(as.character(breakdown[1,])))
    rightHand <- max(nchar(as.character(breakdown[2,])))
    if (is.na(rightHand)) {
      rightHand <- 0
    } 
    print(leftHand)
    print(rightHand)
  }
}
```

is able to properly convert to string and count the digits as intended. The remaining problem that I believed would be solved by fixing the issue with calling the variable is that print doesn't execute for each iteration of the loop.

When running the code my output is

```
[1] 2
[1] 0
```

and I can see that breakdown is showing the correct values for the last variable. Meaning it had successfully looped through everything but instead of printing the largest values for each loop it just prints on the last loop.

Comment: Is `test2` exactly the same as `test` that you shared in the post? Are you sure there's not a different structure there? Using a built in dataset, `iris$Sepal.Width` is the same as `iris[,2]` is the same as `iris[[2]]`. The one that would be different is `iris[2]` which would return a data.frame rather than a vector.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for mentioning that I did not catch the difference. You're right test is the data I created in R, but test2 is the same data saved to .sav and imported back into R since I need the function to interact with haven attributes in the end, and I didn't realize doing so would import it as a tibble and not a dataframe.  

Now the function does seem to loop properly but still has the issue of not printing properly, I thought it was caused by the same error but I guess not, is my syntax wrong there? It just prints the result of the last variable and not all variables

Comment: Please share the `dput()` of the actual data used so we can run and test the code ourselves. It's not clear to me now exactly what's happening.

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide the desired output of the full data frame `test`? I am still a bit unclear. Also, what happens if there is no decimal?

Comment: Your example using "*i.e. c(45.677,3.4) would return "2 3"*" which indicates you want the max number of characters; this seems different from your example table "V4", which you indicate you want 4 and 56 returned - the max values of the numbers themselves (from before/after the decimal in 4.56000). This is definitely doable but please clean up the question a bit for clarity. Good luck!

Comment: Hi all, I cleaned up the question a bit and hope it provides some more clarity into what I'm hoping to do and where the snags in the road are popping up.

Comment: Your problem is `i in ncol(test2)`. That's basically saying `i in 4` so it's only doing the last loop. You either want `i in seq_along(test2)` or `i in 1:ncol(test2)`